# Asynchronously add views to fragment in Android

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, android

I am trying to create a fragment which at the beginning will show a ProgressBar, other thread will call a function which will bring some information (the information brought from remote server - takes few seconds) to populate some views which will be added to the fragment. I have tried to add the views to the fragment but got an exception that I can't change the UI on threads that are not on the main thread. So I run it on the UI thread, but here the problem is that the UI stacked until the moment that all the information brought back from the server.

here is my code:

```
public class MainSalePage extends SherlockFragment 
{
    protected View maneSalePage;
    protected List<SaleObj> saleList;
    protected int numberOfsalesOnScreen;
    protected LinearLayout saleConteiner;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        maneSalePage = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page_fragment, container, false);
        numberOfsalesOnScreen = 0;
        saleConteiner = (LinearLayout) maneSalePage.findViewById(R.id.salesContainer);


        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                SaleService saleService = new SaleService();
                saleList = saleService.getNextSales(numberOfsalesOnScreen); //the operation that takes time.
                for(int i = 0; i < saleList.size(); i++)
                {
                    SaleRow saleRow = new SaleRow(getActivity());
                    saleRow.populateWith(saleList.get(i));

                    saleConteiner.addView(saleRow);
                }
            }
        });

        return maneSalePage;
    }

}
```

How can I show the fragment and not stack the UI till the point I get all my data from the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this it will work, not the cleanest solution, but I like to correct the code not to write new one from the sketch so you can see where did you make a mistake

EDIT: In chat with Vlad a solution guide that helped him

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        maneSalePage = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page_fragment, container, false);
        maneSalePage.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                addContainer();
            }
        }               
        }, 1000);
        return maneSalePage;
    }

        private void addContainer(){
            numberOfsalesOnScreen = 0;
            saleConteiner = (LinearLayout)       maneSalePage.findViewById(R.id.salesContainer);

           SaleService saleService = new SaleService();
        saleList = saleService.getNextSales(numberOfsalesOnScreen); //the operation that takes time.
        for(int i = 0; i < saleList.size(); i++)
        {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {                       
                        SaleRow saleRow = new SaleRow(getActivity());
                        saleRow.populateWith(saleList.get(i));  
                        saleConteiner.addView(saleRow);

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

You were sending all of them at once, and this way you send one by one

EDIT: Don't forget this is going to create all N = saleList.size() threads at once.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work

Comment: Thanks, but still even so, the fragment will wait until the for loop will finish and only then show itself on the screen. I want it to show up and then populate it.

Comment: Problem is that you are doing this on onCreate, is there any way to do this after the fragment is initialized?

Comment: I don't care to do it after it is created. if it is possible.

Comment: Try edited answer see the difference is `saleConteiner.post(` this should force saleContainer to be displayed first then start executing all of the statements.

Comment: you mean that instead of `saleConteiner.addView(saleRow)` put `saleConteiner.post(saleRow)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30321/discussion-between-vlad-ioffe-and-marko-lazic)

Comment: Marko, please, could you clarify, if UI become blocked after 1 second delay for the same period of time as in original version.

Comment: how you decided 1000, if data is fetched from internet?

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to start, for example, an AsyncTask to download all data from server in background thread. AsyncTask has useful handlers OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute, that are guaranteed to run in UI thread. So you can place a "loading" placeholder text on PreExecute and, when your data is downloaded, populate your Fragment with it in onPostExecute.

In rarest case, if you want you data to appear gradually as you download it, use onProgressUpdate handler in pair with publishProgress method.

Comment: The asyncTask is not good for me because I have multiple task for each service class I have (like SaleService).

Comment: I think the AsyncTask, as alexei suggests, is the one you should use. It is a nice _standard_ component every Android developer knows how to use (or should) which improves your code's maintainability. Note that if you really want to you could have multiple AsyncTasks running in parallel by providing different handlers (for different threads) to the execute() method. If you have multiple tasks that can be performed in sequence, however, I would stick to AsyncTask's publishProgress() method, like alexei also mentions.

Comment: So for each call to my remote server should be on an different AsyncTask?

Comment: if your are using Service to download your data, then you shoud bind the service and implement BroadcastReceiver with onReceive automatically called in UI thread. But this is totally another matter.